# How to use FirstOrDefaultAsync() in async await WEB API's

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asynchronous, async-await

I have created one .NET Core API , where my all methods are asynchronous but there is one requirement like `GetBalance()` which just return one entity (record) only.

I am not able to using `SingleOrDefaultAsync()`, getting error like does not contain a definition  for this.

I am using simple basic EF Code First approach with no Repository pattern.

**Here is my code example.**

```
public async Task<ResponseBalanceModel> GetBalanceFor(int accountNumber)
{
    var result = await _dbContext.Accounts.Where(x => 
             x.AccountNumber == accountNumber)
             .SingleOrDefaultAsync(); // this is not working.

    /*Below tried code are not working. 
    var result1 = await _dbContext.Accounts.Where(x => x.AccountNumber == accountNumber).SingleOrDefaultAsync();

    var result2 = await _dbContext.Accounts.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.AccountNumber == accountNumber);
    */
 }
```

For more clarification

[image]

Reference of Entityframework in my project. (.NET Core)

[image]

Comment: You mentioned `await` in your title but yet I don't see it in your code...

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working" ?

Comment: Use *await* after equal sign.

Comment: While Kirk and Ali are solving your problem saying you miss `await`, I think it's worth telling you could use [`.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => [...]);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.singleordefaultasync(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.SingleOrDefaultAsync``1%28System.Linq.IQueryable{``0},System.Linq.Expressions.Expression{System.Func{``0,System.Boolean}}%29) instead of `.Where(x => [...]).SingleOrDefaultAsync();`

Comment: @KirkLarkin : For now I have implemented this way 
var result = _dbContext.Accounts.Where(x => x.AccountNumber == accountNumber).SingleOrDefault();

I have updated the comment. please check

Comment: @AliRasoulian I have tried that too... but still it's not working the reason is SingleOrDefaultAsync() does not exists

Comment: Are you missing `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file?

Comment: @Rafalon I have tried that too but still it's not working

Comment: @Rafalon: No, It's included already. If I remove this then my all LINQ query will stop working which is not in my case.

Comment: double-check your code, you wrote `Asybc` instead of `Async` in your `result1`, and you used `First` instead of `Single` in your `result2`.

Comment: that's a typing mistake here and it will throw compile time error... but in my code I am not getting SignleOrDefaultAsync() option.

Comment: try to install ef core package again from nuget package manager

Comment: @ershoaib.. I have tried by creating one new project.. but it will be more helpful if you give me any specific version for EF.

Comment: You need using System.Data.Entity; to use FirstOrDefaultAsync

Comment: @Matt: not working means this is line is not compiling.. reason is SingleOrDefaultAsync() method does not exists.

I can see SingleOrDefault() or FirstOrDefault() but not with Async.

Comment: Have you added using System.Data.Entity to your usings? SingleOrDefaultAsync() is an extension method and won't be available unless you have added the appropriate namespace.

Comment: @J.Loscos is right you need to add `using System.Data.Entity;` namespace to you project

Comment: @J.Loscos.. No brother it was not working too. :( I have tried.

Comment: What version of EF are you using? FirstOrDefaultAsync was added in version 6 I think. Those methods are defined in the class System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.

Comment: @J.Loscos Please check the post I have added all references that I have in my project.

Comment: Got the solution just installed 
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
in my .net core project and it start working... Thank you all guys for your comments. 

Please like this comment so that other will also get solution for this type problem. 

Thanks again.

Comment: but it already installed in your project how then it solves your problem?

Comment: @ershoaib actually in default package what you can also see in my post does not have Methods like FirstOrDefaultAsync() and SingleOrDefaultAsync() we have to install this additional package.

Comment: @ershoaib please check the answer comment for more clarification.

Answer (score 16):

The EF Core async extension methods are defined in the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore namespace. This namespace must be imported for the methods to be available.

Comment: I should have tried this answer before installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools suggested in the previous answer.

Answer (score 10):

Got the solution just installed!

Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
in my .net core project and it start working... Thank you all guys for your comments.

**Reason :**

1. System.Linq namespace does support ToListAsync(), ToAsyncEnumerable(), and FindAsync() and SaveChangesAsync()
2. To work with FirstOrDefaultAsync() and SingleOrDefaultAsync() method we have to install this package.

Thanks again.